# How to check if all elements of a tuple are elements of other tuple in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tuples

So I have two tuples, lets say seq_a and seq_b. I want to print "True" if every element of seq_a is also an element of seq_b.

Please don't suggest a function, I want it done using loops, or if-else etc

I tried using the for loop but can't quite figure out the syntax.

```py
seq_a = eval(input("Enter a tuple: "))
seq_b = eval(input("Enter a tuple: "))


for i in seq_a:
    if i in seq_b:
        print("True")
    break
else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: What do you want to do in case of duplicates?

Comment: @wim If the 1st tuple has (1,2,1) and the 2nd tuple has (1,2), I would like the result to be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print `"False"` and `break` when `i` is not in `seq_b`, and if all are (the `else` clause), print `"True"`:

```
for i in seq_a:
    if i not in seq_b:
        print("False")
        break
else:
    print("True")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways. The "in your face" way is to use a loop

```
result = True
for i in seq_a:
    if i not in seq_b:
        result = False
        break
print(str(result))
```

you could do the same thing using list comprehensions

```
result = all(i in seq_b for i in seq_a)
print(str(result))
```

or as suggested by one of the other answers, you could use set operations

```
result = set(seq_a).issubset(set(seq_b))
print(str(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just tweak your code so it remembers if something isn't in the other tuple?

```
all_the_same = true
for i in seq_a:
    if i not in seq_b:
        all_the_same = False
        break

print(all_the_same)
```

Alternatively, write a function to just return whether or not they're the same:

```
function test_tuples(seq_a,seq_b):
  for i in seq_a:
    if i not in seq_b:
        return False
  return True

print(test_tuples(seq_a,seq_b))
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert the tuples to Sets and use set difference.

```
 Set(tuple1)-Set(tuple2)
```